# Copy within one SQL Table

Tags: sql-server

I have Table A, i need to replicate some lines in this table forcing one of the fields with a value, this field isn't the primary key but it will make the lines diferent from all the others.

Comment: Need more details + some samples would be good.

Comment: One other thing, there are allready some lines inserted manualy, that can't be considered or it will not run beacause of value duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert` to copy rows into the same table.  This example copies `col1` and `col3`, but uses a new value for `col2`:

```
insert  Table1
        (col1, col2, col3)
select  col1
,       'NewCol2Value'
,       col3
from    Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

> insert into TableA (col1, col2, col3, othercol)
>       select col1, col2, col3, **'fixedvalue'**
>       from TableA

A full copy would be

> insert into TableA (col1, col2, col3, othercol)
>       select col1, col2, col3, othercol
>       from TableA

Assumptions:

1. The primary key is an identity column and is not listed as a column in the queries above - because its value is auto-populated
2. `Othercol` is the column you want to provide a fixed value for. Here it is a string, but any number, date etc would do

Comment: This look's good, but one more question, can I add in this query the "WHERE NOT EXISTS" code?
Thanks.

Comment: @Mike Why would there be "WHERE NOT EXISTS" when the change makes the record different? If that is the only column that changes, either (1) the PK is an identity, so no issue; or (2) PK needs also to change, but it would be tricky to change that for all rows uniquely